# SQL issues with foreign keys in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am new to SQL so please don't bash my skills i am still learning. I am learning SQL and i have created a database for college administration system, The tables i create are working perfectly, but its when i insert the data i get the problem.

Here is my script:

http://pastebin.com/1yew4h7n

When i add the data i get an issue stating that their is an integrity violation and that the primary key in another table can't be found. I get this with a lot of tables. Any help will be great.

O BTW i am using Oracle SQL plus to build the database

Thanks
Michael

Comment: FYI: we use www.sqlfiddle.com here often as it lets you do more with it.  However your DDL is a bit too large for them.  As far as the problem goes: master tables must have records first with key generated before they can be used in the subordinate tables. So... lookup tables populated first. then main tables, then associative tables.  Order matters.

Comment: First, it doesn't make a lot of sense to go to an external site (that is often blocked by firewalls) to post your code when you can (and should) be putting that code in your question.  Second, the first step in any problem is to isolate the actual issue.  I'll wager, for example, that you don't need all the tables in your example.  If you reduce the problem to, say, two tables, it is much more likely that you'll figure out the problem yourself.  But even if that doesn't happen, your question will be much simpler and, thus, many more people will be able to quickly provide assistance.

Comment: the ENROL_ID being insert into tblpayment 101, 102, 103... don't match those records inserted into tblEnrol (201, 202, 203...)  The order building inserts must come before department, and the PK of campus doesn't match the values being inserted into building.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I've got most of it worked out...
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aa77d/4/12

Teacher and subject had to be in the SQL window as they caused the DDL to surpass the 8000 limitation on the site.  Without knowing if the data was sourced or how the records for insert were created... I don't know what updates to make.  So I simply made them so the updates and schema would build.

The order of the tables for insert is in the above fiddle.  Changing order may cause problems.

The problems you have with key violations are due to missing parents so either the child key is simply wrong, or the parent is missing (or wrong). I don't know which is correct.  I randomly updated the needed parents or child records to get a full build/compile but you'll need to update the data for accuracy.

there were 4 or 5 integredity constraint problems if you add data one table at a time and resolve the constraints in the order of tables listed, you should be able to get it going.

- INSERT INTO tblCourse
- INSERT INTO tblStudent
- INSERT INTO tblEnrol
- INSERT INTO tblQualification
- INSERT INTO tblCampus
- INSERT INTO tblPayment
- INSERT INTO tblBuilding
- INSERT INTO tblDepartment
- INSERT INTO tblTeacher
- INSERT INTO tblSubject